# Appending div with image in android < 4.4 webview not working?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, webview

I'm appending this with jquery to an absolutely positioned parent with display table, all the styles are inline at the moment:

```
<div id='bb-contain' style='color:white; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 3.5vw;'>

    <div id='bb-countryHome' style='text-align: right; float: left; width: 35%; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;'>HOME</div>

       <div id='bb-score' style='text-align: center; float: left; width: 30%;'>
           <img src='flags/image1.png' width='19%' style='padding-bottom:5%;'></img>&nbsp;
           <span style='color: yellow;'>76 - 61</span>&nbsp;
           <img src='flags/image2.png' width='19%' style='padding-bottom:5%;'></img>
       </div>

    <div id='bb-countryAway' style='text-align: left; float: left; width: 35%; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;'>AWAY</div>

</div>
```

If I remove the div around the scores / flags then the images display:

```
<div id='bb-score' style='text-align: center; float: left; width: 30%;'>
```

This behaviour doesn't occur on Android > 4.3, can anyone please explain what the problem is?